# Image Button change size onClick

Tags: android, image, button, onclick

On Android Studio I made an image perform like a button. Though what I can't find anywhere is how do I make it so when I click on the image aka the button it becomes a bit smaller and when you release it comes back to original size. Ik that onClick you can perform functions and activities and what not but how do I change the actual button image so as I'm holding down the click button it gets smaller and when i release it comes back to its original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selectors to achieve that. For example define this in your drawable folder:
selector_state_xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

And use this as your View drawable:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/your_button"
 android:background="@drawable/selector_state_xml"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

An alternative could be using [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html)